# Excel VBA Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have created a user form that allows the user to retrieve data from previously entered data and make updates or view the records. I have this built on a few forms and they work perfectly fine. However, on this specific sheet, it is giving me an error and I cannot figure out how to solve it.
I have tried Activating the sheet prior to Set without success. I have literally the exact same script on a different spin button for a different sheet and it works fine.

```
Private Sub SpinButton2_SpinUp()

        Set TicketReviewTable = Sheet2.ListObjects("Tickets")   <<This is where the error occurs.
   
    If TicketReviewTable.ListRows.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If CurrentRow > 1 Then
        
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow - 1
           
        UpdateTicketRecord
    
    End If
    

End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton2_SpinDown()

        Set TicketReviewTable = Sheet2.ListObjects("Tickets")  <<This is where the error occurs.
    
    If CurrentRow = TicketReviewTable.ListRows.Count Then Exit Sub

    If CurrentRow < TicketReviewTable.ListRows.Count Then
    
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
          
        UpdateTicketRecord
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That means that no table named `Tickets` exists on `Sheet2`. First step would be to check the spelling. Also make sure that `Sheet2` is the sheet you think it is.

Comment: `Sheet2` refers to the `CodeName` - The name of the sheet you see in the little tab at the bottom might be different.

Comment: Try please: `Debug.Print Sheet2.Name`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`?

Comment: Thank you, @BigBen ! I replaced "Tickets" with the name of the table "TicketReview" and it works. I must have changed the table name at some point and not updated everywhere. Thank you!